# CNTK evaluation for image classification

Tags: python, image, classification, cntk

I built an image classifier using CNTK. The images are grayscale. Therefore, I entered the number of channels as 1. So, the model requires (1x64x64) data (64 being the image height and width).

The problem is, when I try to predict the class of a new image, it is seen as (64x64) only. So, the code errors out due to data mismatch.

Therefore, I reshaped the image using:

image_data = image_data.reshape((1, image_data.shape[0], image_data.shape[1]))

This generated (1x64x64) - which worked. Though the predictions are coming the same class for every image I select. I wonder if it is because of this reshaping or not. Can someone chime in? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reshaping your input would not affect the output of the model.  If it is only predicting one class for every image, it is an issue with model training.  I would suggest you try predicting on your training data to see if it only predicts one class on the training data.  If that is the case, it is definitely a model training issue.

Comment: Good point! I just did. The training predictions are all the same as well. I'm screwing up somewhere in training, but I can't seem to figure out!

Comment: Try some of the ideas at [this link](https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607) to see if it helps.  It presents a lot of the common reasons for issues with learning.